# Python/Kivy Crash on add_widget function

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Fair warning, I'm new to Python and Kivy, so I may be doing something quite clearly wrong.  I'm trying to dynamically create a grid using Python/Kivy.  The error is happening on this line:

```
for c in range(rows):
    for d in range(cols):
        self.myBoard.add_widget(BoardSquare(x=c+1,y=d+1)) #Error occurs this line
```

I initially received an error related to _disabled_count.  Following this [guidance](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.mapview/pull/41/commits/25c3ba7bac95e7d740a83fd151057486527327d5), I set _disabled_count to zero.  Now it runs, but then crashes within the native Kivy add_widget function.  It appears to stop here:

```
if index == 0 or len(self.children) == 0:
   self.children.insert(0, widget)
   canvas.add(widget.canvas)
```

Here, the code fails on the canvas.add action.  The app crashes overall, and the Python interpreter does not generate an error string.  The only item printed is:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

From other research, I understand that this indicates some sort of segmentation violation, but I"m not sure how to address that.  I'd greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

I'm running Python 3.7/Kivy 1.11/Max OSX

Full code below for reference.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class BoardSquare(Widget):
    myLabel = StringProperty("")
    myX = NumericProperty(0)
    myY = NumericProperty(0)
    myCoord = ReferenceListProperty(myX,myY)
    cor = ListProperty((1,1,.5,1))
    _disabled_count = 0                    #Added to circumvent _disabled_count error

    def __init__(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.myX = x
        self.myY = y
        self.myLabel = str(self.myX) + str(self.myY)

class Board(GridLayout):
    myRows = NumericProperty(0)
    myCols = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Board, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.myRows = 5
        self.myCols = 5

    def resize(self, r, c):
        self.myCols = c
        self.myRows = r

class FieldCommand(Widget):
    myBoard = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FieldCommand, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        rows = 5
        cols = 5
        self.myBoard.resize(r = rows, c = cols)

        for c in range(rows):
            for d in range(cols):
                self.myBoard.add_widget(BoardSquare(x=c+1,y=d+1)) #Error occurs this line



class FieldCommandApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return FieldCommand()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FieldCommandApp().run()
```

FieldCommand.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<BoardSquare>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, .5, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    Label:
        font_size: 10
        top: self.top - 2
        left: self.left + 2
        text: self.myLabel

<Board>:
    size: 1000,1000
    padding: '2sp'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    size_hint: 1, None

<FieldCommand>:
    myBoard: aBoard

    canvas:

    Label:
        font_size: 50
        center_x: root.width/2
        top: root.top - 5
        text: "Field Command"

    Board:
        id: aBoard
        center: self.parent.center
        cols: self.myRows
        rows: self.myCols
        spacing: 20,20
```

Comment: Typo: change `super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)` to `super(BoardSquare, self).__init__(**kwargs)`

Comment: Thank you for your patience. That got me passed the segmentation error.

Comment: probably you can use `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in all classes.

Comment: your code works without crash on Linux but it gives different error: `self.myBoard.resize(r = rows, c = cols)  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resize'`. Maybe because `myBoard` is `None` property, not widget - `myBoard = ObjectProperty(None)`

Comment: Having correct the typo pointed out by @eyllanesc, you should also remove the unnecessary `_disabled_count = 0`.

Comment: From the comments above, I did remove the _disabled_count line.  I was able to achieve the desired effect from there.  Thanks everyone for your patience - as I said, new to the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the comments above, I was using the wrong arguments in my Super argument calls.

I changed all calls to: `super().__init__(**kwargs)`